# Rails cannot load such file -- models/helpers/days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

I have made a helper file in: `models/helpers/days.rb`

However, I try to use my helper in my controller, and it throws up with the following error:

```
cannot load such file -- models/helpers/days
```

I use the following require:

```
require 'models/helpers/days'
class MyController < ApplicationController
```

Is there anyway I can use my days.rb file in my controller?